# Expected constant in 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays

```
double rainPerMonth(const int YEARS)
{
   int monthYear[MONTHS][YEARS];
   // ...
}
```

Visual Studio shows a squiggly line underneath the array declaration, saying that `YEARS` must be a constant when I'm creating the array. Is this an IDE issue because the variable has yet to be initialized, or am I writing this incorrectly?

`MONTHS` is already declared globally.

Comment: "Visual is throwing me a squiggly" awesome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An array size must be a constant expression - that is, a value known at compile time. (Some compilers offer C-style variable-length arrays as a non-standard extension, but I don't think Visual C++ does. Even if it does, it's better not to rely on such extensions.)

A function argument isn't known at compile time, so can't be used as an array size. Your best option is here is probably

```
std::vector<std::array<int, MONTHS>> monthYear(YEARS);
```

Comment: I'm going to research your answer to understand what's happening in it, as I'm new to c++, but I'm wondering if I could initialize it with a constant 1 and append monthYEAR based off of user input within the function.

Comment: @JustinGrahn Not with an array.  You *can* do that with either a `std::vector` or dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: So what would you suggest if one index is fixed and the other variable?

Comment: Nah it's not wrong just makes my skin crawl a bit ;p

Comment: @MikeSeymour: A vector of size `MONTHS*YEARS` with 2D-indexing implemented on top.

Comment: If I know the user cannot pass a fixed number(10) would it be smarter to create a large 2d array and leave it partial, only iterating over the filled space, or still use the vector? I'm assuming the compromise  difference here is space(array) vs. performance(vector) at runtime?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: You'd need that if both dimensions were dynamic; but I don't see how it's an improvement here. You'd have the same memory layout, and the same indexing arithmetic; the only difference is that you'll have to write the indexing yourself rather than letting `vector` handle it for you. Personally, I prefer "not writing code" to "writing code".

Comment: @JustinGrahn: The main difference is flexibility: a vector allows any size (up to some, probably very large, limit); an array requires you to choose an upper bound. Another issue is that a very large array might not fit on the stack, so you'd need dynamic allocation anyway.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, an array must be sized at compile time.  What you are attempting to do is declare one that is sized at runtime.  In the function you've declared, `YEARS` is only constant within the scope of the function.  You could call it `rainPerMonth(someInt);` where `someInt` is the result of some user input (which shows you that the result is not a compile-time constant).

Variable Length Arrays are an extension to C, but not C++.  To do what you want, you can use dynamic memory, or a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in the fact that C++ wants a constant in the sense of compile-time constant to create your variable `monthYear`. If you pass it as a function, it need not be known at compile time? For example:

```
const int x=2;
const int y=3;

char xyChoice;
std::cin >> xyChoice;

if (xyChoice == 'x')
rainPerMonth(x);
else
rainPerMonth(y);
```

I'm unsure, but it seems to me like this would give you a constant int being passed to your function, but the compiler wouldn't know what size to create an array for before runtime?